# Ios app getting Exception object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

My app is working fine on simulators of both iphone and ipad but when i debug to ipad device it is giving an exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

```
Details det = viewController.Storyboard
                            .InstantiateViewController ("DetailstoryboardId") as Details;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;
det.Title = tableItems [indexPath.Row].Title;
UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB (119, 185, 187);

Constants.Root.NavigationController.PushViewController (det, true);
```

Comment: please share code sample.

Comment: I faced this problem earlier, real device is case sensitive but simulator is not. so if their is image named A.png and you use this image name in your code like a.png it will work fine, but in real device you will face problem.

Comment: then what can i do to solve this

Comment: so use name as it is, may be this will solve your problem.

Comment: Sanjeeth,all image names are correct but it getting same exception

Comment: which **specific** object is it saying is null?  You should be able to easily determine this using the debugger.